# What happens in Newtonian mechanics when a particle reaches infinite force position?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, singularities

Suppose a particle of negligible mass is placed at e.g. $x=1$ inside a one dimensional space with a force field generated by the gravitational attraction of a point mass at the origin $0$. I.e. the force is (normalized) $$-\frac{ {\rm sgn} (x)} {x^2}.$$

Then after finite time, the particle will move to the origin.

However, at the origin, its speed is infinite, and I'm not sure how to calculate what happens after it has reached the origin. Can I get a hint for how to do this?

Comment: You are assuming a point mass at the origin. Any real, massive object would have some size and the singularity would not be present.

Comment: I think Not_Einstein has the closest to an answer, it's unphysical to have a central potential without some sort of mass causing it, so there is no position of infinite force for the test mass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The situation at the origin is a singularity, but it can be worked around if you leverage symmetry (and assume no collision takes place). Simply make a special case that acceleration for $x = 0$ is $0$. This makes the situation well defined again. Assuming that origin is reached at time $t$, after a time $2t$ the particle will move to the other side, i.e. $x = -1$. It will then keep oscillating.

Comment: Don't you still need to decide how you will handle diverging speeds though?

Comment: In Newtonian mechanics, I see no problem. The only issue might be that even a very small mass will diverge slightly away from the center (since it would slightly move the point mass), making the speeds close to the origin vastly inaccurate. However, this can be set right in the limit case (which is what negligible tends to mean anyway).

Answer (score 0):

At the origin the force is undefined, so the acceleration is undefined. "Infinity" is not a number, so technically you can only define the trajectory up to $x=0$ but not at $x=0$. You would need to bring in some other assumption to handle what happens at the origin. You could probably think up various assumptions, one of which is covered in [Kotlopou's answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/564342/179151), although IMO it still seems a bit "hand wavy".

Comment: Since the question does not correspond to a real physical situation, I don't see any problem with redefining it this way, as that seems the most natural way to keep the mathematical structure "pure" and the resulting differential equation interesting. Yes, an infinite acceleration over an infinitely short distance is undefined, but you are flying through it at infinite speed, so the time spent accelerating is "doubly infinitesimal". I imagine there exists a more rigorous phrasing expressing the intuition that the origin is irrelevant.